# How can i get Data from Wikidata by a specifc keyword in Java or Android

Tags: java, android, wikidata

i want to progamm an android app, which can automaticly generate statements. But before i can build the statements i need information from wikidata.

I just need a possibility to enter a Keyword and i will get all informations about it.

Should look like this:

Input:

```
     "New York"
```

Output:

```
     "population: 8,405,837, 2016; 8,175,133, 2010;........"

     "head of gouverment: Bill de Blasio, 1 January 2014;........."
    .
    .
    .
```

With this data i could build my statements like: 
"The population of New York is 8,405,837 since 2016" (For de Statement building i dont need help only for the extraction of the data)

i need a method like:

```
public String getDataByKeyWord (String keyWord ){
String data;
.
.
return data;
}
```

I hope you can help me its very Important for me.
And sorry if i made mistakes, its my first time here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may find everything you need here https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Toolkit

Wikidata being structured data (as opposed to wikipedia) you'll be able to navigate through it in a more data structured way